# Symmetry factor of diagram for scalar field formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams

In 2010, [Dong, Hue, et all.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0859) find the formula

> $$S_{Diagram} = g 2^\beta 2^d \prod_n (n!)^{\alpha_n}$$

where we have an interpretation about each of these numbers. In this equation the symmetry factor $S$ is a function $S = S(g,\beta,d,\alpha_n)$ where

1. $\beta$ is the number of lines that connect a vertex to itself
2. $d$ is the number of double-bubbles in the diagram
3. $\alpha_n$ is the number of vertex pairs with $n$ same contractions

> My question is, how can I understand $g$ in this formula.

The text uses a lot of examples but to me it is not clear in the examples and in the text what the authors are considering in this $g$.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the notation used is a little misleading but as stated in the article on p.4,

> "$\dots g$ is the number of permutations of vertices that leave the diagram unchanged with fixed external lines."

This is to say that $g$ is the number of viable permutations one can make that result in a  topologically indistinct diagram. In particular, vertices connected directly to external lines are *not* subject to interchange because those lines originate from labelled and distinguishable source points, which define the distinct entries in your $n$-point correlators, each at some coordinate $x_i$.

The trivial case of $g=1$ corresponds to the identity permutation, i.e there is no non-trivial permutation one can perform on the diagram that will result in a topologically indistinct diagram. This is all exemplified on p.8-9 of the text, where they give diagrams pertaining to the zero and two point correlator with $g=1$ and $g=2$.